# (godot) how to access autoload file by using variable?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

i made a autoload file named "saveLoad.gd"

The content of "saveLoad.gd" is:

```
var a = 0
var b = 1
```

then, i tried to acess "saveLoad.gd" file in this way:

```
var items = [a, b]

func store(itemname):
    if saveLoad.itemname == 0:
        itemname.visible = false

func _ready:
    store(items)
```

(there are a button named "a" and "b")
but it doesnt work well

i think because engine recognize saveLoad.itemname as variable in "saveLoad.gd"

not saveLoad.a or saveLoad.b

How can i make this work?

edit)
The comment code block doesn't look good, so i'll add modified code here

```
func store(itemname:Array):
    for i in range(0, len(itemname), +1):
        var itemname2 = itemname[i]
        if Savenload.get(itemname2) == 0:
            get(itemname2).visible = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve done the following in the modified code below:

Used the get() function

Added a loop for the store() function to retrieve each item out of the store() which is an array.

Modified code:

```
var items = ["a", "b"]

func store(itemname):
    if saveLoad.get(itemname) == 0:
        itemname.visible = false

func _ready():
    for item in items:
        store(item)
```

Comment: actually, this code dosent work well(it's possible that i made a mistake)
but when move loop into func store(itemname) like this:
func store(itemname:Array):
 for i in range(0, len(itemname), +1):
  var itemname2 = itemname[i]
  if Savenload.get(itemname2) == 0:
   get(itemname2).visible = false

it works! Thank you for the clue :)